# LaTeX Error: Command \numdef already defined

Tags: macros, errors, overleaf

This error is linked to “/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoobox.sty, 1003” by the system. I do not know what this really means though I do find such definitions in a file of texlive 2023 with the same path installed in my computer’s C: drive.

The detailed information of this errors reads as follows:

```
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              
l.1003   \edef#1{\the\numexpr#2}}
                                  
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
23676 strings out of 477679
459511 string characters out of 5829514
763038 words of memory out of 5000000
42069 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
470967 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
98i,1n,94p,437b,79s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
No pages of output.
```

The following is the working environment:

```
% if your latex compiler failed to compile, uncomment the command below:
%\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{clv3}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\let\oldemptyset\emptyset
\let\emptyset\varnothing
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=darkblue, linkcolor=darkblue, urlcolor=darkblue}
\bibliographystyle{compling}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{linguex}
\begin{document}
 content
...
\end {document}
```

The system now fails to compile. Hope this is the (only) cause for it. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File \`clv3.cls' not found.`   please link to this class.

Comment: `latexrelease` should not normally be used, don't specicfy`booktabs` or`linguex` twice

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidCarlisle. I commented the (latexrelease) out and delete the two repetitive packages.  One more question: Do you mean the `\documentclass{clv3}` does not link to this "clve.cls"? Or what can I do to link to this class? Thanks again.

Comment: no, I mean give a url in the question where we can download `clv3.cls` it is not in texlive so your example stops with an error on the `\documentclass`

Comment: I see. It is [clv3.cls link](https://cljournal.org/style.html). It's the first file in the list on that page.

Comment: File compiles fine on my side if the line `\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}` is uncommented. I am using the latest version of TL 2023

Comment: Thanks.  I fixed it. The TL 2023 is not yet available in Overleaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite simple. The `clv3` class does

```
\def\numdefname{Definition}
\newtheorem{numdef}{\numdefname}
```

but `etoolbox` also wants to define `\numdef`.

It's easy to fix this by aliasing the `numdef` environment, but there's a worse problem: the class also redefines `\document`, which is a very *bad thing*: see [Problem with Computational Linguistic Template - COLI - CLV3.cls](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/627415/4427)

```
% save the kernel \document and \enddocument
\let\latexdocument\document
\let\latexenddocument\enddocument
%%%

\documentclass{clv3}
% restore the original
\let\document\latexdocument
\let\enddocument\latexenddocument

% add to the standard hooks
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\openout\@mainqry=\jobname.qry
  \fi
}
\AtEndDocument{%
   \ifx\@biography\@empty\else{\par\ifbrief\vskip10pt\fi\biofont\noindent\@biography\par}\fi
   \immediate\closeout\@mainqry
   %\ifquery
   %   \process@queries\clearpage
   %\else
      \ifodd\c@page\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\clearpage\else\clearpage\fi
   %\fi
   %\ifquery\clearpage\else\ifodd\c@page\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\clearpage\else\clearpage\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

% alias numdef to cnumdef
\NewCommandCopy{\cnumdef}{\numdef}
\NewCommandCopy{\endcnumdef}{\endnumdef}
\let\numdef\relax \let\endnumdef\relax

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldemptyset\emptyset
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,citecolor=darkblue, linkcolor=darkblue, urlcolor=darkblue}
\bibliographystyle{compling}

\begin{document}

 content
...

\end {document}
```

Note the placement of `\usepackage{hyperref}`, which should come last.

Comment: Thanks! @egreg I copied the code in my main.txt, but it produced similar command errors on the new name. I guess I can just for now comment out the two new commands  as I never need them in the main.txt. Then the command error is gone. Also, thanks a lot for your reminding of the placement of the  `usepackage{hyperref}`. Fixed it too. Though the compilation still doesn't work, it's a good start :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. Now it successfully compiles~~ The thing is, after executing the suggested code, the compilation produced an unexpected blank page (the last but two pages where the conclusion text is broken). I wonder if this has something to do with the suggested code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The strange thing is that a footnote supposed to be on the last but one page, i.e. p55 (where the two-column bibliography starts) appears on this empty page, p54.

Comment: BTW, the doc is printed on both sides.

Comment: @JCY Please, open a new question, showing a short example of a failing document.