Undefined control sequence for \@thefnmark with clv3 V3.3 (Computational Linguistics journal template)
When using TeX Live 2024 to compile a document that uses V3.3 (2023-02-02) of the Computational Linguistics journal template clv3, I get the following error:
! Undefined control sequence.
\@footnotetext ...@footnote\endcsname \@thefnmark 
                                                  }\color@begingroup \@makef...
l.11 \maketitle

Following is a minimal example triggering the bug; it applies the fix for the redefined \numdef problem that was reported for using TeX Live 2023 with an earlier version of clv3.  (The current version of clv3 seems to have fixed at least one the other incompatibilities reported in that answer.)
\documentclass{clv3}

% alias numdef to cnumdef per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/688309/22603
\NewCommandCopy{\cnumdef}{\numdef}
\NewCommandCopy{\endcnumdef}{\endnumdef}
\let\numdef\relax \let\endnumdef\relax

\begin{document}
\pageonefooter{Test} % This line seems to be the culprit
\maketitle
\end{document}

I assume this new problem has something to do with recent changes to LaTeX's internal footnote code, though I can't figure out exactly what changed and how to adapt the clv3 code to work with it.

no the error was always there. They use internally \@footnotetext without defining \@thefnmark.

May a call to \footnotetext (without @) be a proper solution? With the change of appropriate line in clv3.cls to \ifx\@pageonefooter\@empty\else\let\domkfnmark\relax\def\dofnformat{\vskip\baselineskip}\footnotetext{\@pageonefooter}\fi (just removed @ from original line), Test is printed as footnote without marks, not sure if it is supposed to work so.
